# What does the symbol <<< mean?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

Can anyone give the LaTeX code for the unusual symbol <<<, and perhaps provide some good examples of its use?

Does it mean "much much less than"?

Comment: Try `\lll` which gives $\lll$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the common uses of that symbol are, because $\ll$ already means "very much less than" in a way that is hopefully clear from the context, e.g. saying that the ratio of the left-side to the right-side goes to $0$ in some limit, for example. Or, that given the right-side, the left-side is less than some very small function of the right-side. So if we already use $\ll$, I don't know what "extra meaning" that $\lll$ could have. Note the use of $\ll$ is already somewhat ambiguous enough to discourage its use in rigorous math proofs. But I see it in physics and stats arguments.

Comment: Isn't $\ll$ used for "Big-O" notation sometimes ... I seem to remember this from somewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a cursory search, it appears that the [triple less-than sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign#Triple_less-than_sign) $\lll$ is not often used in a *mathematical* context but in a programming one (maybe an experienced programmer or two can weigh in). From the wiki page:

- In PHP, operator `<<<OUTPUT` is used to denote the beginning of a heredoc statement (where OUTPUT is an arbitrary named variable).
- In Bash, `<<<word` is used as a "here string," where word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input, similar to a heredoc.

At least in mathematics, it is clear that something like $a\ll b$ means "$a$ is **much less** than $b$." Other than that, however, it does not appear that the symbol $\lll$ is used in mathematical contexts (none that I have seen anyway). A look at the [wiki page on inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_%28mathematics%29) yields similarly fruitless results for trying to find that symbol/notation in math.